# Reduce paragraph line break height on iTextSharp

Tags: itext, line-breaks, paragraph

How can I reduce the height of a line break which occurs when a paragraph length is too long for the width of the ColumnText?

I've tried the following, as I've seen other questions which answered with this:

```
p.Leading = 0
```

But this has made no affect.

I've also tried increasing the `Leading` to `100` to see if a larger line break is added, but neither work.

SpacingBefore/SpacingAfter doesn't help either:

```
p.SpacingBefore = 0
p.SpacingAfter = 0
```

How can I reduce this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using a table, you need to set the leading on the cell itself. However, you'll see that the `Leading` property is read-only so instead you'll need to use the `SetLeading()` method which takes two values, the first is the fixed leading and the second is the multiplied leading. According [to this post here](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Line-spacing-in-IText-td2149280.html#d1171065588000-598):

> Multiplied basically means, the larger the font, the larger the leading.  Fixed means the same leading for any font size.

To shrink the leading to 80% you'd use:

```
Dim P1 As New Paragraph("It was the best of times, it was the worst of times")
Dim C1 As New PdfPCell(P1)
C1.SetLeading(0, 0.8)
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I saw "Column" and my coffee-lacking brain went to tables.

For a `ColumnText` you should be able to use the Paragraph's leading values just fine.

```
Dim cb = writer.DirectContent
Dim ct As New ColumnText(cb)

ct.SetSimpleColumn(0, 0, 200, 200)
Dim P1 As New Paragraph("It was the best of times, it was the worst of times")
''//Disable fixed leading
P1.Leading = 0
''//Set a font-relative leading
P1.MultipliedLeading = 0.8
ct.AddElement(P1)
ct.Go()
```

On my machine running iTextSharp 5.1.2.0 this produces two lines of text that are slightly squished together.

Comment: Cheers for your reply, but I'm not using a `PdfCell`. The paragraph is being added to `ColumnText`

Comment: Cheers Chris, however this still isn't working for me :/ I'm also using 5.1.2.0 so I'm a bit baffled as to why its not working. Any other ideas at all?

Comment: Hmm I've copied your code in and can see its squashed, whereas when adding it to my code its not working. Hmm I'll have to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ahh your using `AddElement` whereas I've been using `AddText`. I've changed it, and hurray! it works! The only thing is, this seems to be messing up the value of `ct.YLine` which I use to then position another columntext beneath it.

Comment: Actually I don't think this is a problem. Obviously the YLine is going to change if the Leading is changed I guess. Cheers Chris great help!

Comment: @Curt, if you use `AddText()` then you can set the leading on the `ColumnText` the same as I was for a `PdfPCell`.

Comment: I think I tried that but it didn't work, either way its all sorted. There was a fix in my code to do something like `YLine - 10`. I believe the `-10` was to patch the gap the paragraph was causing. However, this gap no longer exists so just had to remove the `-10`. Much neater :)

Answer (score 4):

Well it seems you've stumbled upon the difference between *text mode* and *composite mode*:

- text mode => call `ColumnText.AddText()` using the "inline" Chunk and Phrase objects.
- composite mode => call `ColumnText.AddText()` using "container" objects like Paragraph, Image, etc

When you're in *text mode*, you add space between "paragraphs" by setting `ColumnText` properties.

When you're in *composite mode*, you add space between "container" objects as you normally would - i.e. as you would if not using `ColumnText`.

Here's an example to show the difference between the two modes::

```
int status = 0;
string paragraph ="iText ® is a library that allows you to create and manipulate PDF documents. It enables developers looking to enhance web- and other applications with dynamic PDF document generation and/or manipulation.";
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, STREAM);
  document.Open();
  ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
  ct.SetSimpleColumn(36, 36, 400, 792);
/*
 * "composite mode"; use AddElement() with "container" objects
 * like Paragraph, Image, etc
 */
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(paragraph);
// space between paragraphs
    p.SpacingAfter = 0;
    ct.AddElement(p);
    status = ct.Go();
  }

/*
 * "text mode"; use AddText() with the "inline" Chunk and Phrase objects
 */
  document.NewPage();
  status = 0;
  ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    ct.AddText(new Phrase(paragraph));
// Chunk and Phrase are "inline"; explicitly add newline/break
    ct.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
  }
// set space between "paragraphs" on the ColumnText object!
  ct.ExtraParagraphSpace = 6;
  while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(status)) {
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(36, 36, 400, 792);
    status = ct.Go();
  }  
}
```

So now that you've updated your code and are using composite mode with `AddElement()`, `p.SpacingAfter = 0` **WILL** remove spacing between paragraphs. Or set it to whatever you want instead of `Paragraph.Leading`.