# Support for leading in irregular columns?

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp 5.5.1 and am laying out a document using irregular columns. Irregular columns are always rendered in **text mode**.

I need to be able to set the leading for the paragraphs in my irregular column, but am not able to do so - the calls to `ColumnText.SetLeading` are ignored.

```
Dim doc As New Document
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream)

doc.Open()

Dim column As New ColumnText(writer.DirectContent)
column.SetLeading(fixed, multiple)

column.SetColumns(New Single() {...}, New Single() {...})

column.AddText(New Paragraph(""))
column.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE)

column.AddText(New Paragraph("..."))
column.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE)

    ...

column.Go(False)
```

The generated PDF has the same leading regardless of what values I use for `fixed` and `multiple` in the call to `ColumnText.SetLeading`. I can adjust the spacing after each paragraph using `ColumnText.ExtraParagraphSpace`, but I am unable to set the leading within each paragraph.

I did find a related SO question and answer, [Reducing paragraph line break height on iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094461/reduce-paragraph-line-break-height-on-itextsharp/9100813#9100813), but that talks about setting the spacing *after* a paragraph ends. This works in irregular columns, but I'm interested in the leading, which is the space between the lines within a paragraph.

Comment: Scott, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9100813/231316) which describes the difference between text and composite mode. Since you are using `Paragraph` objects you need to use the leading on those objects and not the `ColumnText` itself.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, thanks for the response. I am using irregular columns, so it is being rendered in *text mode*. The answer you linked to talks about how to specify spacing after the paragraph in text mode, which is great and works, but I'm interested in specifying the leading, which is the space between the lines within a paragraph.

Comment: Sorry Scott, I see that now. I can't reproduce your problem, what are you using for `fixed` and `multiple`. When I use `48,0` and `0,4` I get pretty much the same thing, all lines very spaced out. If it helps, the ultimate equation for leading is `fixedLeading + (multipliedLeading * maxFontSizeOfAllChunksInPhrase)`

Comment: @ChrisHaas, thanks for sticking with me on this. I am not onsite where this problem happened, and won't be again until next week. I just tried reproducing the problem on my local environment and the leading appears to work. I'm going to need to explore this more next week when I'm back in front of the code where this problem was occurring. Maybe it has to do with the iTextSharp version? I'll keep you update, and thank again.