# Adjust height of Chunk.NewLine ItextSharp C#

Tags: c#, itext

I have to display a column with two string and blank line between it, Below is snippet i am using.

```
Pharse heading = new Pharse("Header");
Pharse footer= new Pharse("Footer");

Paragraph label = new Paragraph();
label.Add(heading);
label.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
label.Add(footer);
```

However, I notice that the height of blank lines are too big. How can I reduce it?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to achieve what you want. Let me start with what I think is the easiest way. If you have a `Paragraph` and you want it to be followed by some extra space, you can use the `SpacingAfter` functionality:

```
Paragraph label1 = new Paragraph("Header");
label1.SpacingAfter = 15;
Paragraph label2 = new Paragraph("Footer");
document.Add(label1);
document.Add(label2);
```

As you can see, I split the `label` into two objects. Fact is that every `Paragraph` object has a *leading*. This *leading* defines the space between lines, and it is identical for every line in the `Paragraph`. It can be expressed as (a combination of) an absolute distance and a relative distance based on the font size. See Chris Haas' answer to the question [Reduce paragraph line break height on iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094461/reduce-paragraph-line-break-height-on-itextsharp)

If `heading` and `footer` consist of a single line, you could reduce the space taken by the `Chunk.NEWLINE` by reducing the value of the leading. For instance:

```
Phrase heading = new Phrase("Header");
Phrase footer= new Phrase("Footer");
Paragraph label = new Paragraph();
label.Leading = 12;
label.Add(heading);
label.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
label.Add(footer);
```

The disadvantage with this method is that the distance between two lines of text will be reduced too. For instance: if `heading` consists of a much longer text, the lines will be split and the distance between those line will be reduced too.

You could also work with a combination of both solutions. For instance: split your `Paragraph` into three parts: `heading`, the new line chunk, and `footer`. Wrap the new line chunk into a separate `Paragraph` with a small leading.

**Note:** all measurements in PDF are expressed in user units. By default, there are 72 user units in one inch. In other words: a leading of 12 user units is 1/6 of an inch.